# Laravel 6.0.* Passport doesn't work with php-fpm+nginx : "The GET method is not supported for this route" when POST sent

Tags: laravel, nginx, oauth, laravel-passport

For my backend API application I have Laravel 6 with Laravel Passport oAuth2 plugin. Im my `routes/web.php` I'm using `Auth::routes();` to make all oAuth routes. My Nginx config (Running on Amazon instance):

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf`

```
server {
    server_name  my-app-domain.net;
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    root   /var/www/app/public;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.php;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }  

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


    error_page  404  /index.php;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /index.php;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|otf|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        root    /var/www/app/public;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If I send POST with `grant_type` and other login credentials to `http://<domain name>/oauth/token` I'm getting this weird ERROR:

> "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this
>   route. Supported methods: POST."

Aside from that the other API requests are working fine, so probably its not a CORS restrictions

However if I run `php artisan serve` and send POST to `http://localhost:8080/oauth/token` it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about CORS. Despite I have installed `barryvdh/laravel-cors` package and settings are set to "*" the CORS was still the issue. So I had to tweak a bit Nginx

```
server {
server_name  my-app-domain.net;
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 20M;

include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
root   /var/www/app/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;

index index.html index.php;
charset utf-8;
.....
```

Plugin `barryvdh/laravel-cors` has to be deleted as well